# Posting to Facebook app group via ajax is failing silently

Tags: ajax, facebook

Thank you in advance for any assistance you maybe able to provide. I'm trying to post from my app to an app group that I have created. Using the code below it completes the request successfully but the data returned is empty. Please tell me what I'm doing wrong. I did also notice that it's not performing a POST but rather a GET.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.1/'+g_id+'/feed?access_token='+User["User AccessToken"],
    data: JSON.stringify({
        message: g_mes
    }),

    dataType: "jsonp", 

    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function(data1){
        console.log(data1);
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really should use the JavaScript SDK for the API. Here is a basic tutorial: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart/v2.1

And this is what the API call would look like:

```
FB.api('/' + g_id + '/feed', 'post', {message: g_mes}, function(response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

See Facebook docs for a code example too: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/group/feed

You don´t even need to worry about the Access Token. You just need to use [FB.login](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/v2.1) with the appropriate permissions in the scope parameter to authorize the user.

Comment: When I do that I get an error of Unsupported post request. I know that the user(myself) has given permission for user groups and publish actions. I have not asked for these permissions from Facebook yet, but I was under the assumption that I could test using the app administrator without having to get permission first. Thank you for trying though.

Comment: yeah, you can definitely test with the app administrator without review.

Comment: are you sure g_id is correct and a group the user is a member of? i´ve added a link to the docs, the example code looks exactly the same.

Comment: I wonder whats wrong, I literally cut and paste your code and it guves me the error.

Comment: imho only 2 things can be wrong: either g_id is not correct, or the user is not authorized correctly with FB.login.

Comment: make sure you call FB.api after FB.init btw, just in case you don´t. and of course after authorization.

Comment: https://graph.facebook.com/v2.1/correct_group_id/feed?access_token=token&message=hhhhhhhhhhhhhhh&method=post&pretty=0&sdk=joey is the call that it generates. The id points to https://www.facebook.com/groups/1510360075870235/ which is correct and its my own account so I can verify that I'm logged in with the correct permissions.

Comment: yeah, that does look correct, actually...maybe you can try it directly in the graph api explorer for testing? (with the select box set to POST and stuff): https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/

Comment: (#200) Insufficient permission to post to target on behalf of the viewer       So, it looks like, even though I'm the developer it will not let me agree to publish_actions permission. That's silly, how am I supposed to make sure its working before I ask for permission without first testing the app. Ohh well, looks like your answer was right. Thanks you very much.

Comment: maybe it´s different for groups, you could try posting to your own feed. you only need publish_actions for that. so if that does not work either, it´s a problem with the user authorization.

Comment: btw, you can also try to put the access token in the debugger, it will tell you if the permissions are really there: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

Comment: LOL, that's silly. In the graph explorer for the app I granted myself every possible permission. I then generated an access token and used it within the graph explorer as a post. It still said not enough permission. That's just funny, lol. I guess maybe its a group thing, not an api thing since even the graph explorer won't let me publish to the group.

Comment: yeah, it makes sense, else someone could just create an app without approval and spam all the groups where he is a member of.